# Referencing WinRT/UWP libraries in a .NET desktop application while maintaining support for Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, network-programming, connection, desktop-application

I am trying to reference "Windows.Networking.Connectivity" classes in my desktop application. I am basically interested in handling metered connections in my app.

Basically what I am trying to do is simple:

```
var connectionCost = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile().GetConnectionCost();
            if (connectionCost.NetworkCostType == NetworkCostType.Unknown
                    || connectionCost.NetworkCostType == NetworkCostType.Unrestricted)
            {
                //Connection cost is unknown/unrestricted
            }
            else
            {
                //Metered Network
            }
```

The only method I know of that allows a desktop application to reference UWP assemblies is by manually editing the project file and adding the following line to the csproj file:

`<TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>`

Applying the code and "hack" works fine but the problem is that doing so will prevent my app from running on Windows 7 which I need to support.

I was wondering if there is a way to reference UWP assemblies in a desktop application without having to drop support for Windows 7.

And since for the time being I only want to check if a connection is metered, I am open to suggestions about how to get this information without referencing Windows assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to use reflection and call UWP methods without having to specify a target platform. For my case this is what I did:

```
var networkInfoType = Type.GetType("Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation, Windows, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");
            var profileType = Type.GetType("Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation, Windows, ContentType=WindowsRuntime");
            var profileObj = networkInfoType.GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("GetInternetConnectionProfile").Invoke(null, null);
            dynamic profDyn = profileObj;
            var costObj = profDyn.GetConnectionCost();
            dynamic dynCost = costObj;

            var costType = (NetworkCostType)dynCost.NetworkCostType;
            if (costType == NetworkCostType.Unknown
                    || costType == NetworkCostType.Unrestricted)
            {
                //Connection cost is unknown/unrestricted
            }
            else
            {
                //Metered Network
            }
```